# What are the combinations of ch, sh, th, wh, ph called in the professional literature jargon?

Tags: terminology, jargon

What are the combinations of the consonants **ch, sh, th, wh, ph** called in the professional literature jargon? (I'm asking about the consonants that are represented by two letters).

Comment: I guess you mean linguistics, not literature.

Answer (score 5):

They are called **consonant digraphs**.

> **Consonant blends** (also called consonant clusters) are groups of two or
>   three consonants in words that makes a distinct consonant sound, such
>   as "bl" or "spl."
>
> **Consonant digraphs** include bl, br, ch, ck, cl, cr,
>   dr, fl, fr, gh, gl, gr, ng, ph, pl, pr, qu, sc, sh, sk, sl, sm, sn,
>   sp, st, sw, th, tr, tw, wh, wr. Some trigraphs are nth, sch, scr, shr,
>   spl, spr, squ, str, thr.
>
> There are also digraphs that produce a distinct vowel sound. Some
>   examples are: ai, au, aw, ay, ea, ee, ei, eu, ew, ey, ie, oi, oo, ou,
>   ow, oy. ([source](https://www.enchantedlearning.com/consonantblends/))

Comment: Hm, I would still distinguish between some of these, that are just the sounds of the two consonants “flowed together,” as in `bl` or `gr` or whatever, while others are distinctly separate (“single”?) sounds different somewhat from the sounds of the constituent letters, as in `ch`, `ng`, `ph`, `sh`, and `th`. Would there be a term, perhaps, that is specific to the latter?

Comment: @KRyan To add, I'd say that the grapheme combination `ch` doesn't represent a single phoneme, but a phoneme combination /tʃ/ (though I do not find good minimal pairs to demonstrate  this out of the blue). Still. neither does `c` usually correspond to /t/, nor `h` to /ʃ/, so I guess `ch` still deserves to be grouped with `ng`, `ph`, `sh`, `th`, `gh`, `sc` and perhaps a few more, but we do have a different phenomenon from `bl` etc.

Comment: @Hagen I would argue that the /tʃ/ affricate is actually a single phoneme, because it is not treated as separate. It isn't perceived at t + sh, but as its own sound. And, when you do force t and sh together (e.g. "it should,") it is not perceived as ch. As such, I propose the term to be "phonemic consonant digraph."